# Count the number of digits in a bash variable

Tags: bash, shell, digits

I have a number `num=010`. I would like to count the number of digits contained in this number. If the number of digits is above a certain number, I would like to do some processing.

In the above example, the number of digits is 3.

Thanks!

Comment: Does `${#num}` do what you want?

Comment: Can that variable contain any non-digit characters?

Comment: @EtanReisner, please add that as an answer

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Assuming the variable only contains digits then the shell already does what you want here with the length [Shell Parameter Expansion](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion).

```
$ var=012
$ echo "${#var}"
3
```

Comment: This doesn't work if `var` is assigned the result of a command; instead it returns the length of the command. Instead use the answer from @anubhava

Answer (score 12):

In BASH you can do this:

```
num='a0b1c0d23'
n="${num//[^[:digit:]]/}"
echo ${#n}
5
```

Using awk you can do:

```
num='012'
awk -F '[0-9]' '{print NF-1}' <<< "$num"
3

num='00012'
awk -F '[0-9]' '{print NF-1}' <<< "$num"
5

num='a0b1c0d'
awk -F '[0-9]' '{print NF-1}' <<< "$num"
3
```

Answer (score 3):

Assuming that the variable x is the "certain number" in the question

```
chars=`echo -n $num | wc -c`
if [ $chars -gt $x ]; then
   ....
fi
```

Answer (score 2):

this work for arbitrary string mixed with digits and non digits:

```
ndigits=`echo $str | grep -P -o '\d' | wc -l`
```

demo:

```
$ echo sf293gs192 | grep -P -o '\d' | wc -l
       6
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `sed`:

```
s="string934 56 96containing digits98w6"
num=$(echo "$s" |sed  's/[^0-9]//g')
echo ${#num}
10
```

Using `grep`:

```
s="string934 56 96containing digits98w6"
echo "$s" |grep -o "[0-9]" |grep -c ""
10
```